# No known class method for selector presentViewController in UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

I know it is a very simple question and i am working on it since 3 hour but didn't able to make it working. I am trying to implement UIAlertController to show error message using [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html), but i am getting error on this line that no known class method for selector presentViewController `[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];` I searched and got many solutions but none is working here. AlertMessageViewController is my custom class, which is inherited from UIViewController.

```
AlertMessageViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AlertMessageViewController : UIViewController
+(instancetype)showAlert: (NSString *) title withMessage: (NSString*) message preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyle)preferredStyle;
@end

AlertMessageViewController.m

#import "AlertMessageViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AlertMessageViewController ()
@end
@implementation AlertMessageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
+(instancetype)showAlert: (NSString *) title withMessage: (NSString*) message preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyle)preferredStyle
{

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"alertMessage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){NSLog(@"ok action");}];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why you have extended your AlertMessaveViewController with UIViewController? and How are you using this class and method. No wonder you get an error.

Comment: Cause UIAlertController is inherited from UIViewController. I have commented on uros19 answer that how i am calling this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is your return type for showAlert: method instancetype? And you didn't return anything, it should be void.

EDIT: Also, your method shouldn't be Class method

this should work:

```
-(void)showAlert: (NSString *) title withMessage: (NSString*) message preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyle)preferredStyle
{

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"alertMessage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){NSLog(@"ok action");}];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

UPDATE:
Okay try this:

```
  +(UIAlertController*)alertWithTitle: (NSString *) title withMessage: (NSString*) message preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyle)preferredStyle
{

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle: preferredStyle];
UIAlertAction *ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){NSLog(@"ok action");}];
[alert addAction:ok];
return alert;
}
    }
```

Then when you want to show it, call it like this:

```
[self presentViewController:[AlertMessageViewController alertWithTitle:@"Title" withMessage:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert] animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: -(void)loginCustomUser
{
 if([[self.emailTextField text] isEqualToString:@""] ||    [[self.passwordTextField text] isEqualToString:@""])
  {
      [AlertMessage showAlert:@"Error" withMessage:@"Enter Email and Password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    }
}

Comment: Check update, should work this way, are u calling this method in AlertMessageViewController? If not, the problem is in [self presentViewController] method because self is pointing on AlertMessageViewController, not on your current ViewController

Comment: thanks, its working now. I understand the problem too, as u said. Cause i was calling this method in another ViewController.